# What events should I choose to track GRANT, REVOKE statements in Extended Events Session?

Tags: sql-server, extended-events

I didn't find any event that corresponds to tracking **GRANT**, **REVOKE**

I tried `object_altered`, `object_deleted`, `object_created` with no luck.

Comment: Can you use SQL Server Audit instead?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/event-classes/audit-database-object-gdr-event-class?view=sql-server-ver16